# ViewData not being posted back to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two pages, one that edits user information, and one that edits information in a pictures table.  I recently stopped using strongly typed viewmodels due to the varying types of data required on each page.

The page that edits the user information works fine, but the page that edits picture information does not post back any of the edits that are made in the input fields; except for the ID, which is correct, all the other values come back as null.  They both seem to be structured exactly the same way -- I can't figure out what's the difference.  As far as I can tell the code for both pages are the same, but I'm not getting data back on the second one.

**User Controller and View which works**

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Preferences()
{
    int userid = getUserID(User.Identity.Name);  

    // Info for user preferences
    var accountInfo = db.users.Single(l => l.ID == userid);  

    ViewData["accountInfo"] = accountInfo;

    AccountController usr = new AccountController(); // Info for user menu
    ViewData["userInfo"] = usr.getUserInfo(User.Identity.Name);

     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Preferences(user accountInfo, string oldPW)
{
    // Do stuff to save user info
    return RedirectToAction(actionname, routeValues);
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Preferences", null, FormMethod.Post, 
                                            new { id = "prefsform" }))
{
AutoShowApp_MVC.user item = new AutoShowApp_MVC.user();
item = ViewBag.accountInfo;

<input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" value="@item.lastname"/>
<input id="address1" name="address1" type="text" value="@item.address1"/>
<input id="city" name="city" type="text" value="@item.city"/>
<input id="state" name="state" type="text" value="@item.state"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Changes"  />

}
```

**Picture Controller and View which DON'T work**

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(long id)
{
    var picInfo = db.lmit_pics.Single(l => l.ID == id);
    ViewData["picInfo"] = picInfo; // get Picture Info

    // Get User Info for menu
    AccountController usr = new AccountController(); 
    ViewData["userInfo"] = usr.getUserInfo(User.Identity.Name);

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(lmit_pics picInfo)
{
    // Do stuff to save picInfo
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editform" }))
{
    AutoShowApp_MVC.lmit_pics item = new AutoShowApp_MVC.lmit_pics();
    item = ViewBag.picInfo;
    <input type="text" id="model" value="@item.model" />
    <input type="text" id="description" value="@item.description" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
}
```

Comment: Why in the world are you using such pattern? Even if you found where the problem is you should consider to use ViewModel and EditorTemplates

Comment: I was using this method initially, and agree that it is ideal, but I couldn't figure out how to pass both user info, and page info, at the same time.

Comment: Wahid, actually, now that you mention it, I was failing to realize that I can use both strongly types views for the main page data, and ViewBag data for the rest of the stuff. That might help a little.

Comment: If you design your ViewModels well and made sufficient EditorTemplates you'll put nothing in the ViewBag or ViewData but the small View needed values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the name attribute specified on the inputs on your picture editing form.

```
<input type="text" id="model" value="@item.model" />
```

Should Be

```
<input type="text" id="model" name="model" value="@item.model" />
```

The form collection works from the name attribute, not the Id attribute which is why you are not getting any data back (you are, it is just not properly attributed).

However, I agree with Wahid above, using strongly typed view models, editorFor helpers, etc not only help to prevent issues such as the above, but really go a long way in making a more secure, easier to maintain site.

Comment: With strongly types views, I could not figure out how to pass information to the 'user dropdown' and the page data, at the same time.  I'm sure there must be a way, but I don't know how, at the present time.

Comment: Gotcha, well when you get more time to refactor or whatnot, post to SO, we are here to help!  On that line, drop downs in MVC have always been a PITA to me, but I usually create a Dictonary<key, value> on the View Model for the Dropdown, then use the drop down helper as such:  @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SomeModelIdFromDropDown, new SelectList{Model.MyDictonaryOfValues, "key", "value"}).  Seems to be the best way so far of getting those darn things to work easily :)

Comment: Actually I was overlooking something VERY basic, which is strong types and Viewbag data can be mixed on the same page.  I was erroneously thinking that it had to be one way or another.  I'm going to fix all of this, thanks, and thanks for that 'name' solution, I had no idea.